# Bulma Image not full width

Tags: css, bulma

So as i want to add multiple images in a row i would like the image not to take the full width. In the Bulma doc they only tell you how to force them to use the full width but not how not to.

The containers work fine but they just use the whole page which is clearly not usefull if you want to show more at once.

I tried the column class but that doesnt work out.

[image]

This is how it has to look like in the end.

Answer (score 1):

Using columns, and Bulma helper classes you can make each column fit the content it holds without resizing the images:

```
  <div class="columns">
    <div class="column is-half">
      <h3>In Theatres</h3>
      <div class="columns is-flex-wrap-wrap">
        <div class="column is-narrow">
          <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150x200">
        </div>
        <div class="column is-narrow">
          <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150x200">
        </div>
        <div class="column is-narrow">
          <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150x200">
        </div>
        <div class="column is-narrow">
          <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150x200">
        </div>
        <div class="column is-narrow">
          <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150x200">
        </div>
        <div class="column is-narrow">
          <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150x200">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="column is-half">
      <h3>Movie of the day</h3>
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/600x460">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```